# Getting fingerprint from Apache certificate (combined with key)

Tags: apache, https, security-certificate

I have just created a certificate for my Apache SSL host using:

```
make-ssl-cert /usr/share/ssl-cert/ssleay.cnf /etc/ssl/private/myhost.crt
```

Now what is the correct way to get the fingerprint out of it?  (So I can keep it in other place for visual comparison---in case I need to connect and really don't trust the network?)

```
openssl sha1 /etc/ssl/private/myhost.crt
```

Returns a different SHA1 than what Opera tells me about the cert.  Is this because it's combined with the key?

(...or am I spoofed already? :-)).

Comment: What do you get if you perform `openssl x509 -in /etc/ssl/private/myhost.crt -sha1 -noout -fingerprint`?

Comment: Your command openssl sha1 /etc/ssl/private/myhost.crt Dosn't work cos it computes the sha1 checksum of the whole certificate file, HeatfanJohn's answer is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this command to determine the SHA1 fingerprint:

```
openssl x509 -in /etc/ssl/private/myhost.crt -sha1 -noout -fingerprint
```